# Use dictionary keys in FOR loop to specify a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am trying to specify a list in a `for` loop using the keys from a dictionary added to a string. Let me explain:

```
site1_switches = {
    'visw0102' : {
        'device_type': 'hp_comware',
        'ip': '192.168.0.241',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'password'
    },
    'visw0103' : {
        'device_type': 'hp_comware',
        'ip': '192.168.0.242',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'password'
    },
    'visw0105' : {
        'device_type': 'hp_comware',
        'ip': '192.168.0.244',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'password'
    }
}
uplinks_visw0102 = ['GigabitEthernet1/0/1','GigabitEthernet1/0/2']
uplinks_visw0103 = ['GigabitEthernet1/0/48']
uplinks_visw0105 = ['GigabitEthernet1/0/1','GigabitEthernet1/0/48']

for key, values in site1_switches.items():
    for port in ('uplinks_' + key):
        print(port)
```

Now this is not all the script but it's the part I am stuck at with the elements needed for it to run as it is.

I was expecting `port` to contain `uplinks_visw010X` depending on where it is at in the loop. Instead, here's what I am getting:

```
>>> for key, values in site1_switches.items():
...     for port in ('uplinks_' + key):
...         print(port)
...
u
p
l
i
n
k
s
_
v
i
s
w
0
1
0
2
u
p
l
i
n
k
s
_
v
i
s
w
0
1
0
3
u
p
l
i
n
k
s
_
v
i
s
w
0
1
0
5
>>>
```

It seems that evey character in `port` is processed by the loop but it's not what I want it to do.

How should the `keys` be processed for them to, when combined with a string, come out as I expect them to (`uplinks_visw010X`).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval()` is something that you require here. The eval function lets a Python program run Python code within itself. One of useful applications of eval() is to evaluate python expressions from string.
You can update your code, to make use of `eval()` like this:

```
>>> for key, values in site1_switches.items():
...     for port in eval('uplinks_' + key):
...         print(port)
... 
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/2
GigabitEthernet1/0/48
GigabitEthernet1/0/1
GigabitEthernet1/0/48
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it works! I will read on the eval() function. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy Learning @Noct03!